# When is a good idea save static files ( images, js, css, etc ) in a subdomain?

Tags: php, hosting

The question is simple:

When is a good idea save static files ( images, js, css, etc ) in a subdomain ? and when is not a good idea ? and why ?

Right now, I am using a shared hosting, but in the future I will use a dedicated server.

Thanks

Comment: The idea behind hosting static files on another domain is to allow the clients browser to make separate requests for static data. You can also configure specific caching for those files. Files can also be served without cookies, reducing transferred size.  This post answers the question:http://serverfault.com/questions/357402/using-subdomain-on-same-server-good-or-bad-why

Answer (score 1):

It's not the subdomain that has any relevance, it's the content delivery mechanism that  is relevant....

If your site has high traffic such that performance is poor or your current host is unable to keep up, it can make sense to offload the serving of commonly requested or large-size assets (images, video, some CSS or Javascript, etc) to a more specialised content delivery server.

For example, I use Amazon's CloudFront Content Delivery Network (CDN) to serve all my static images. It is much faster at serving **static** content (it caches the content in several edge locations around the world), and it frees up my server to perform better in processing and serving dynamic content (dynamic PHP and CSS files). Until recently, amazon's CDN could only serve static files, so it made sense that way.

I map my own subdomains to the Amazon CDN server, but you don't have to -- there's no requirement saying thay you have to map a subdomain to do that. You can use your content delivery provider's default URL if you prefer.

So how do you know if your site would benefit from serving of static assets from a CDN? I made the assessment using [YSlow](http://yslow.org). TSlow profiles your site responsiveness and speed and makes recommendations to speed up the site. I measured before and afterwards and saw an improvement. Be careful though -- it's easy to get addicted to profiling! The best gauge is by analysing your user behaviour. Do they give up and leave your site too early? Do people complain about poor performance? If not, then find other areas that may better 
improve your bottom line.